# Expression for "making a big incident/problem as a minor one"

Tags: phrase-requests

Can someone help me finding an expression for "making a big incident/problem as a minor one" by ignoring it or taking it casually?

I want to insist someone to concentrate on the main incident when they deliberately try to ignore the core point and hang on to trivial things.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. We could do with a little more information about how you want to use the expression (jocularly, scathingly...); whether you want an established expression or something "clever" like *making a molehill out of a mountain;* anything else which may help get **just** the right answer. Have a look at the help on [phrase-request](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/phrase-requests/info) questions for some examples of what helps the community to help you.

Comment: @Andrew Leach Thank you . I am struggling to convey my point :l

Comment: I would suggest that the answer is already within the question: **trivializing**. "Trivializing a problem doesn't solve it."

Comment: @Bread thank you .. i think i was looking for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Legitimately 'downplaying' a problem to get it into context is a valid 'de-escalation', in my view, reducing a problem to its true proportion.

But the OP asks for a word which expresses 'ignoring it or taking it casually' which I think makes @Bread 's comment ('trivialize') appropriate :

> To make trivial; to render commonplace or trifling.

[OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/206530?redirectedFrom=trivialise&)

> Never forget — or trivialize — the Holocaust

[Washington Post 27 Apr 2018](https://www.washingtonpost.com/opinions/never-forget--or-trivialize--the-holocaust/2018/04/27/28860464-4965-11e8-8082-105a446d19b8_story.html?noredirect=on&utm_term=.30f8afbe216b)

Answer (score 2):

[downplay](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/downplay)
as in:
The government are trying to downplay the violence which broke out yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

to **play down** (something)  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/play+down)

> to make something seem less important or remarkable.